# navigate using arrow keys in Media Player Classic-HC

Tags: media-player-classic

Today, I installed Media Player Classic-HC and noticed it doesn't use arrow keys for moving forward or backward. I went to `View` => `Options` => `keys` and made the proper changes to my need. But now, there is problem, when I press right arrow key or left arrow key, it pauses the movie instead of jumping ahead. 
What should I do to prevent it from pausing?

[image]

Comment: it could be a problem with the file, does the seek bar work properly?

Comment: @RichieFrame Yeah, seek bar works fine!

Comment: did you make sure that no other command is still using it, like "framestep"?

Comment: @RichieFrame oh, that was it. Thanks. Post it as answer so I can mark it as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing a key hook, it will not automatically disable a different command with the same key option. There is also no feedback given that there is a conflict (that would be nice).

MPC will use the first ID number associated with that key as its command. If you have selected a new key for a comnmand, you have to look through the other commands and make sure that one of them does not have the same key hook or there will be a conflict, preventing one of them from working.